# how to detect empty wav files

Tags: audio-recording

There are some wav files that are empty (though their size is not 0 bytes). Their duration is also 00:00.

When you open these files, nothing happens even if you hit the play button again and again.

Is there a way to filter all such files from a collection of (say 10000) .wav files?

Equivalently, could you help me in filtering all .wav files of duration less than or equal to 2 seconds from a huge collection of files?

Comment: Welcome Snowbell :) If Jim does not solve your issue, might be a good idea to provide some test files to play with... Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Answer (score 2):

If the files have no content then it's enough to key on size. A totally "empty" WAV file will have just a header and will almost certainly be less than 200 bytes. So it's probably enough to delete any files smaller than that. I would sort the folder by increasing size. You will probably see a sharp change from very low values to a series of much larger files. Bulk delete above that point (shift-select, delete).

If the files have some length but contain only silence, you need a more rigorous test. But from your question it doesn't sound like that's the case.